# Star products and Jacobi Identity

Tags: algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, noncommutative-geometry, poisson-geometry

I'm having a "little" problem with one affirmation on [Kontsevich's paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9709040). He says that the second order terms $O(\hbar)$ implies, assuming that the associator $A(f,g,h)=0$, that the Jacobi Identity it's satisfied.

That's my problem, I'm stucked here for days. Using $f*g= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \hbar^{n}C_{n}(f,g)$. Now, the formula for composition gives $f*(g*h)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\hbar^{n}\sum_{k+l=n}C_{k}(f,C_{l}(g,h))$. Taking the second order terms, I got (assuming that the associator is vanishing):

$fC_{2}(g,h)+C_{1}(f,C_{1}(g,h))+C_{2}(f,gh)=C_{2}(f,g)h+C_{1}(C_{1}(f,g),h)+C_{2}(f,gh)$

Thw two terms in $C_{1}$ already gave $[f,[g,h]]$ and $[h,[f,g]]$. And I now, since $C_{n}$ are derivatives that we can combine some of the terms in order 2 in pairs to give just one new term using Leibniz rule. But how can I get the third term, namely $[g,[h,f]]$.

I've searched internet for papers or something else that could bring some light to this and I've found nothing, all authors always assume this and just made the same affirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming you are looking at

> The condition $Q^2 = 0$ can be translated into an infinite sequence of quadratic constraints on polylinear maps $Q_i$. [...] The third constraint means that $Q_2$ satisfies the Jacobi identity up to homotopy given by $Q_3$, etc.

I think that you are misunderstanding what is being said.

In the above passage Kontsevich is talking about the $L_\infty$ structure on a graded vector space. Writing $\{ - \} = d$ and $\{ -, \dotsc, - \}$ for the “higher brackets”, the Jacobi identity in the above passage would look something like
$$
\color{red}{\{ \{ a, b, c \} \}} + \{ \{ a, b \}, c \} + (-1)^{bc} \{ \{a, c\}, b \} + (-1)^{ab+ac} \{ \{ b, c \}, a \} \color{red}{{}+\{ \{a\}, b, c \} + (-1)^{ab} \{\{b\}, a, c \} + (-1)^{ac+bc} \{ \{c\}, a, b \}} = 0
$$
where the red terms involving a ternary bracket (and the unary “bracket”, usually called “differential” and denoted $d$) are what is meant by “up to homotopy”.

All of this is happening in what is sometimes called the “dual picture”. (More info here: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0403135)

Your calculations are not in the dual picture and I don't know how to fix them. One calculation you can do checking that the associativity of $\star$ means that the first term $C_1$ is a Hochschild 2-cocycle.

Comment: Thanks for correction my on what I was confuse. I get the Jacobi identity by assuming A(f,g,h)+A(g,h,f)+A(h,f,g)=0.